# How to make android animation like new Google app, "Playbook for Developers"?

Tags: android-animation

This is the link for the app [Playbook for Developers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.secrets).

these are examples of animations::

[image: Playbook for Developers Animation]

I think, this app use [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html).

However it is very difficult to create a complex animation, unless there is any tool that converts vectors as [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) made ools as Adobe Illustrator into vectors android can identify.

I would be most grateful if you tell me how to make these animations and if there is any tool to make using tools such as Adobe After Effects.

Comment: Use a custom layout with a custom SurfaceView and add a single animation into it. It takes more time than just adding a view like that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unzip the apk and you will find out that they are gif files.
And it seems that they are using https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable to load gif files.